# Why cant I wrap image around text?

Tags: html, css, image, containers, wrapper

Why cant I wrap image around text (put image behind text)?

Css code:

```
.wrap5{
        background-image: url ('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Alto%27s_Adventure_animation_-_01_Chasm.gif');
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class = "wrap5">
<br><br>
<center><h1 style = "color: blue; font-family: monsterrat; letter-spacing: 1px; font-weight: 900;">Are you willing to go on the best journey?</h1></center>
<br><br><br><br>
<center>
<button class = "but" style = "float: center" onclick = "document.getElementById('modal-wrapper2').style.display='block'">Get Started</button>
</center>
<br><br>
<hr>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the white-space between url and the opening bracket:

```css
.wrap5{
        background-image: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e3/Alto%27s_Adventure_animation_-_01_Chasm.gif');
}
```